# Who was John Lark in Mission: Impossible - Fallout?

Tags: character, mission-impossible, mission-impossible-fallout

I don't understand who John Lark was in this. Was he the CIA Agent August Walker?

Answer (score 4):

> Henry Cavill as August Walker, a CIA assassin working for the Special Activities Division tasked with monitoring Ethan and his team. He is also the real John Lark who contacted the Apostles to steal the plutonium cores.

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mission:_Impossible_%E2%80%93_Fallout#Cast) under the Cast section.